# CreateProcessAsUser doesn't work in windows service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

I wanted to make a windows service in c++ to start my programs as administrator every time the user log in without pop up UAC window

As it's the first time for me to do it I used the project from here :
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948/view/SourceCode

I edited line 74 in CppWindowsService.cpp  to this :

```
InstallService(
            SERVICE_NAME,               // Name of service
            SERVICE_DISPLAY_NAME,       // Name to display
            SERVICE_AUTO_START,         // Service start type
            SERVICE_DEPENDENCIES,       // Dependencies
            0,            // Service running account
            SERVICE_PASSWORD            // Password of the account
            );
```

and added some code to the worker thread in SampleService.cpp line 101 to become like this :

```
void CSampleService::ServiceWorkerThread(void)
{
// Periodically check if the service is stopping.
while (!m_fStopping)
{
    // Perform main service function here...

    HANDLE hToken = NULL, dToken;
    WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), &hToken);
    DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, 0, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &dToken);
    STARTUPINFO stinfo = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo = { 0 };
    stinfo.cb = sizeof(stinfo);
    stinfo.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";
    LPVOID pEnv = 0;
    CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv, dToken, 0);
    CreateProcessAsUserW(dToken, L"F:\\test.exe",0, 0, 0, 0,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, pEnv, 0, &stinfo, &pinfo);

    ::Sleep(2000);  // Simulate some lengthy operations.
}

// Signal the stopped event.
SetEvent(m_hStoppedEvent);
}
```

the test.exe located in F drive shows a message box but when I try to run it from a service nothing happen although I can easily use CreateProcess to execute it from ordinary programs

Edit : I also tried put a command line in CreateProcessAsUser but nothing happens

Comment: Check the return value of ``CreateProcessAsUserW``, if it's ``FALSE`` call ``GetLastError`` to find out what's wrong

Comment: for what you call `DuplicateTokenEx` ?

Comment: and `DestroyEnvironmentBlock` must be

Comment: Don't duplicate the token, and close `hToken` after creating the process. Hopefully you're also closing the process and thread handles returned in `pinfo` after you're done with them.

Comment: The bigger problem here is a design fault. " start my programs as administrator every time the user log in". Services start _before_ a particular user logs in.

Comment: @MSalters, that's not a difficult problem, but the OP may not know how to enable the [`SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996) control that notifies a service of session changes, with a session number and status code that's equivalent to a [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828) window message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT as a creation flag in the function and the problem was solved

Comment: there is another thing wrong the created process isn't running as adminstrator , it's running as a usual user but the service as SYSTEM

Comment: because you are running it as an unelevated user, not as SYSTEM.  Have a look at this article: [Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide). It implements a custom `CreateProcessAsUserElevated()` function (amongst others).

Comment: I used  SetTokenInformation with TokenElevationType and TokenElevation to elevate the duplicated token but didn't work , I also didn't find CreateProcessAsUserElevated in microsoft documentation and it doesn't exist in c++ sdk in visual studio . I use windows 8.1 sdk

Comment: If the session user's token from `WTSQueryUserToken` has elevation type `TokenElevationTypeLimited`, then you need to get the user's `TokenElevationTypeFull` token via `TokenLinkedToken`. The full token has high elevation, administrator access, and the full set of administrator privileges. Obviously you need to have and enable SeTcbPrivilege to get it as a primary token.

Comment: @prog511 read my previous comment more carefully. I did not say `CreateProcessAsUserElevated()` was a Microsoft function. It is a custom function created by the author of the article that I linked to.

Comment: you can query for linked token from token returned by `WTSQueryUserToken`, if this is admin user - it have elevated linked token